# Unable to load XML data to table tag Html

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Learning **XML** and stuck at a point where I am **unable to load data from an XML file to Table tag**
It shows me the button made but when I click on the button it performs no task.
Here is my code of

**contacts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<contacts>
    <contact>
        <name> AMIT PAGARIA</name>
        <number>8128817671</number>
    </contact>  
    <contact>
        <name> SUMIT PAGARIA</name>
        <number>9825988688</number>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <name> AMIT PAGARIA</name>
        <number>9327023560</number>
    </contact>
</contacts>
```

**HTML CODE**

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    th, td {
      padding: 5px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <title></title>

    <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Get my Data</button>
    <table id="demo"></table>

    <script>
    function loadXMLdoc()
    {
        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                myFunction(xmlhttp);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET",contacts.xml,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function myFunction(xml)
    {
    var i;
      var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
      var table="<tr><th>Name</th><th>Number</th></tr>";
      var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("contact");
      for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
        table += "<tr><td>" +
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
        "</td><td>" +
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("number")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
        "</td></tr>";
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
    }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(){
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            myFunction(xmlhttp.responseXML);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","contacts.xml",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}


function myFunction(xml){
  var table="<tr><th>Name</th><th>Number</th></tr>";
  var x = xml.getElementsByTagName("contact");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("number")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
```

ps: remember to use loadXMLDoc() instead of an undefined function loadXMLdoc. Your function in the html body is not the same as in the script.

Comment: thank you @hypemichael but still i am unable to get it done!

Comment: It works fine in firefox. Remember to put contacts.xml in quotes. ie "xmlhttp.open("GET","contacts.xml",true);"

Comment: I did whatever you told,
1)Tried it in Mozilla,
2) "contacts.xml"
3) loadXMLDoc() also did

I kept an else condition to the if condition of readyState and status 
such as-

 if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            myFunction(xmlhttp.responseXML);
        }
  else
   document.write("error");
    };

and it is executing the else condition which means that condition is false !

Please Help :(
@hypermichael

Comment: Please post your modified code. Just tested it and it works fine. Also make sure contacts.xml and the html file are in the same folder

Comment: ok it's working, after writing the table tag in document.write
@hypermichael